# How to find signup date for Gmail account?

Tags: gmail, google-account, account-management

I would like to find out the month and year I signed up for my current Gmail account.

Answer (score 4):

- go to **https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/**
- enter **Settings**
- select **Forwarding and POP/IMAP**

[image]

[image]